# How to extract data in rows based on multiple-columns values?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, extract, multiple-columns, rows

I want to extract data from rows based on multiple column values and my code does not seem to work.

I want to create a new dataset with only those rows that satisfy the conditions based on columns values. E.g. I10.I15=1 and C03=1 and C10=1 and D80.D89=0. Therefore, this subgroup should consist only of the rows that satisfy all of those criteria. Specifically, the one I mentioned above should consist of about 267 cases.

I thought I could solve this with the following code, but it seems it takes all the cases that have I10.I15=1 and all the cases that have C03=1, etc. while I only want those people who satisfy all of the conditions together.

```
Xx=data[(data['C03']== 1)] | (data['I10.I15'] == 1) | (data['C10'] == 1)| (data['D80.D89'] == 0)]
```

Comment: You're missing the name of the variable `data`: `data['I10.I15'] == 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. You should swap the | for & if you want it to satisfy all the conditions.
Also doublecheck the brackets.

```
Xx=data[(data['C03']== 1) & (data['I10.I15'] == 1) & (data['C10'] == 1) & (data['D80.D89'] == 0)]
```